# Measure of "Matchingness"/Correlation between polylines

Tags: qgis, arcmap, line, spatial-statistics, geoda

I am working with two layers of polylines that represent different modeled/representative approaches to summarizing aircraft radar tracks.

I am curious if, beyond just visually inspecting them, if there is an appropriate quantitative way of looking at how similar or "related" they are in terms of their direction and turns, etc, rather than something basic like looking at the amount of parts along the polyline layers that do and do not intersect.

I want to say there is a way at looking at a correlation between the two, but something about that seems rather complicated (which I am willing to read more about).  I also am not sure which GIS/spatial data software would be the most useful for this sort of task (i.e. QGIS vs GeoDA vs ArcMap).

Therefore, I am wondering two fold:
1) What sort of statistical test/method would be most appropriate?
2) Which spatial platforms would be best for carrying it out- does someone know specifically which packages/features/commands would be most useful within each platform?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot showing how your two polyline layers look like ?